# Differentiate between .csv and false .csv

Tags: java, csv, mime-types

I have a method that uploads a CSV file. It works fine when I work with any normal CSV file.

The problems comes when it also reads any file (say, PDF) renamed with `.csv` as the file extension and it doesn't throw any exception.

Can anybody help me in differentiating a *bona fide* CSV file and a "fake" CSV file with a `.csv` file extension?

---

#### Update following comment:

**Here is my code:**

```
CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader();
ArrayList <ArrayList<String>> arrData=null;
String path="C:/Users/Avinash/Desktop/asset.csv";
arrData=CsvReader.readCsv(path,printinconsole);
```

The above code works fine if `asset.csv` is a real CSV file. But any other format file (say `asset.pdf`) is renamed to `asset.csv`, it doesn't throw any exception but reads junk values.

Can anybody help in differentiating these two different file types?

I tried [jMimeMagic](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmimemagic/) but it fails to give correct MIME type of all spreadsheets from Open Office.

Comment: Can you describe how you'd differentiate between these two entities in ***words***? If so, then translate that into [insert language of choice here]. Give it a go and ask for help if you have any specific problems in your implementation (tagging the question with the appropriate language). See http://whathaveyoutried.com/ for more info on how to get good answers.

Comment: CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader(); 
ArrayList <ArrayList<String>> arrData=null;
String path="C:/Users/Avinash/Desktop/asset.csv";
arrData=CsvReader.readCsv(path,printinconsole);


The above code works fine asset.csv is real csv file. But any other format file say asset.pdf is changed to asset.csv, it doesn't throws any exception instead read junk values. 
Can anybody help in differentiating these two different file.

I tried jmimemagic but it fails to give correct mime type of all spreadsheet from open office.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: OK. So this is [tag:Java], so we can tag the question accordingly. [If other users ask you for more information in the comments, edit your question using the edit link just below your original question.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask). I've done this for you this time (the first one's free)!

Answer (score 4):

> How to differentiate a bona fide CSV file and a "fake" CSV file with a .csv file extension?

You can not do this in a straight forward way, since each file can be interpreted as a CSV file (records separated by newline, fields separated by comma, so even binary files, using some character set, can be read as "valid" CSV files). If, for example, the file does not contain any newline or comma characters, you would end up with a single record/single field result containing the whole file.

In order to check if it is a valid CVS file (for your use case), you need to validate the result which has been read from the CSV file using some constraints which you know your particular data needs to fullfil. You can, for example,

- validate header / title values
- validate the number of fields you expect in each record
- validate maximum/minimum field lengths and record lengths
- validate the character set - does your data contain invalid characters?
- validate whether the field data is in a specific range?

BTW: You should do these validations anyway, in order to avoid malicious data being imported into your application.

Answer (score 0):

Many file formats have a special header, a short sequence of bytes used as a type signature. It's how Linux can tell a text file from an image, without the need for a specific file extension.

In Java, you can use the utility classes from `javax.activation`. A full example is given [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0487.html).

If your text file is identified as text/csv (or text/plain maybe), then you can try to parse it as such.